# How to authenticate a custom Web application using Tacacs+

Tags: ruby, authentication, web

I'm currently looking for information on how to integrate authentication for a custom web application using TACACS+ We are currently running Nginx on the front and Ruby on the backend.

Also is there any specific gems available for interacting with TACACS+ server.

Thank you for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a TACACS+ PAM module (https://github.com/kravietz/pam_tacplus)

Also there is a Nginx module for PAM: (https://github.com/sto/ngx_http_auth_pam_module)

Combining both would give you what you want: requesting user and password for a URL.  I'm not really sure if this would work in your use case as the dialog would be similar to the basic authentication dialog displayed by a browser.  No user session concept and no way of managing your identity.

I think this is difficult, good luck!